# how to find Chinese numbers from regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am checking 0-9 numbers using re.match(r"^[0-9]+ ", line). like in a same way I need to check there are any Chinese numbers in the beginning of the line. from 一 to 十. do you know any solution for this?

Comment: Could you provide context and some examples? Like input and expected output. Not everybody knows Chinese numbers...

Comment: Funny how `\p{N}` does not recognize these "numbers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try regex `^[一-十]+`:

```
import re

text = '一丁十一xxx'
print(re.search(r'^[一-十]+', text))
```

Prints:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='一丁十一'>
```